# EpiServer XhtmlString richtext is changing my html

Tags: asp.net, episerver, richtext

my html is:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cyber-icon-v"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is the result after pasting to the richtext:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

is there a way to avoid deleting my html?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to register a class that extend the allowed elements, it is called TinyMCEPluginNonVisual, [see this article](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Editing/Customizing-the-TinyMCE-editor/).

This will allow any html element

```
[TinyMCEPluginNonVisual(
    PlugInName = "TinyMceExtendedValidElements",
    AlwaysEnabled = true, 
    EditorInitConfigurationOptions = "{ extended_valid_elements: '+*[*]' }")]
public class TinyMceExtendedValidElements
{
}
```

This will allow divs

```
[TinyMCEPluginNonVisual(
    PlugInName = "TinyMceExtendedValidElements",
    AlwaysEnabled = true, 
    EditorInitConfigurationOptions = "{ extended_valid_elements: 'div[*]' }")]
public class TinyMceExtendedValidElements
{
}
```

Simply add the TinyMceExtendedValidElements in a file in your project and compile add the `using EPiServer.Editor.TinyMCE;` reference